# postgreSQL COPY failing with value too long for type character varying(255)

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to copy a csv file with each column enclosed in double quotes. The COPY statement that I am using is:

```
\COPY schema.table_name FROM 'file_name.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', ESCAPE '\', QUOTE '"', FORCE_NULL(col1,col2,col3,col4))
```

The column 'col3' is defined as VARCHAR(255). One of the rows in csv file has a string that has literal '\n' repeated 4 times, making the length of string 259. I am expecting that each occurrence of '\n' will convert into newline character, making the string to 255 character long. However, the COPY statement is failing with the below error:

> ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(255)
>
> COPY schema.table_name, line 11859, column col3: "RN recommends 3HX3D (Mon, Wed, Fri) of PCA/ service.\nincontinence supplies\nPERS new\nConsumer stat..."

When I change the column length to 260, the COPY works fine. I cannot change the length of the column as I won't know how many '\n' literals may come in this column. Is this a bug in postgreSQL? If not, how can this be fixed? I am using version 12.3 of postgreSQL.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Increase the size. varchar without a size is Ok in Postgres. [you must come from an Oracle or mysql world ?]

Comment: @wildplasser, Thanks for the response! After altering the column and removing the size, the COPY worked just fine.

Comment: I don't think that `\n` has any special meaning in the CSV format, so you might have to sanitize your data.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @wildplasser works fine. I removed the size for VARCHAR column and the data is loaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files do not use \ escaping (except possibly for the quote character itself).  You escape a newline by having it appear literally in the file, but included inside the quotes.  So if you make the type long enough to hold the data, it will still be holding a literal sequence of \ and n, not newlines.

So this is not a bug in PostgreSQL, but rather a bug in your file data.

Comment: that is debatable. I have worked on many csv files that has escape sequences including \n, \t and \r. But it is quite strange how postgreSQL behaves when it encounters escape sequences.